# Finding Coefficients Terms

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am trying to find the coefficients of the following two terms in expansion of $(3x-y^2)^{44}$.

For the first one we need to find the coefficients of $x^{20}y^{48}.$

I found this one by following formula $(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^{k}$
$$(3x-y^2)^{44} = \sum_{k=0}^{44} \binom{44}{k}(3x)^{44-k}(-y)^{2k} \\ \text{Let $k=24$} \\ = \sum_{k=0}^{44} \binom{44}{24}(3x)^{44-24}(-y)^{2(24)} \\ (3x-y^2)^{44}= \binom{44}{24}(3x)^{20}(-y)^{48}$$
Now I am trying to find the coefficients for $x^{28}y^{30}$.

$$(3x-y^2)^{44} = \sum_{k=0}^{44} \binom{44}{k}(3x)^{44-k}(-y)^{2k}$$
But I am stuck here becauseI don't know what $k$ should equal to have the coefficients to be $x^{28}y^{30}$. Is there a better way to find this $k$?

Comment: If there is no $k$ satisfying both $44-k=28$ and $2k=30$, then there is no $x^{28}y^{30}$ in the expansion. Hence the coefficient is $0$.

Comment: I see. So my ways of following the formula for the first one is correct? My fear was that I was doing it wrong so I wouldn't know how to do this one.

Comment: I wouldn't call what you have written particularly *correct* either...  You are using equals signs and keeping summations where they don't belong.  $(3x-y^2)^{44}$ is not "*equal*" to $\binom{44}{24}(3x)^{20}(-y)^{48}$.  No.  The expression on the right is merely one among many of the terms in the expansion of the expression on the left.

Comment: Further, it is incomplete.  We are asking for the coefficient of $x^{20}y^{48}$.  We are not asking for the coefficient of $(3x)^{20}(-y)^{48}$, though that will be helpful in answering the intended question.  To continue, we note that $\binom{44}{24}(3x)^{20}(-y)^{48}=\left(\binom{44}{24}3^{20}(-1)^{48}\right)(x^{20}y^{48})$

Comment: Next... there is an error in how you handled $-y^2$... It is not true that $(-y^2)^k = (-y)^{2k}$.  It should have been that $(3x-y^2)^{44}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{44}(3x)^{44-k}(-y^2)^{k}$ which is different than what you have written.  See for example $(-4)^3 = -64\neq 64=(-2)^6$

Comment: @JMoravitz, thank you for pointing that out! So for the solution of the one you've been vetting, $(3x-y^2)^{44} = \binom{44}{24}(3x)^{20}(-1)^{48}(y^2)^{24}$?

Comment: You've gone and written $(3x-y^2)^{44}$ as being equal to a single term again.  It is equal to the sum of *many* terms, not just one.  **The $x^{20}y^{48}$ term from the expansion of** $(3x-y^2)^{44}$ will be equal to $\binom{44}{24}(3x)^{20}(-(y^2))^{24}=\binom{44}{24}3^{20}(-1)^{24}(x^{20}y^{48})$.  This is just one term of many from the entirety of $(3x-y^2)^{44}$ and is not equal to the entirety of $(3x-y^2)^{44}$

Comment: And again, you continue to handle the $-1$ incorrectly in your most recent comment.  Compare this to the $x^{21}y^{46}$ term which would have been $\binom{44}{23}(3x)^{21}(-(y^2))^{23} = \binom{44}{23}3^{21}(-1)^{23}(x^{21}y^{46})$ which is *negative*.  If you had used $(-1)^{46}$ instead it would have incorrectly been positive.

Comment: If you are frustrated at having to continually type "*The $x^{20}y^{48}$ term from the expansion of $(3x-y^2)^{44}$ is equal to...*" rather than writing an equation, there is notation for this.  We write $[x^{20}y^{48}](3x-y^2)^{44}$ to refer to the coefficient of the $x^{20}y^{48}$ term of the expansion of $(3x-y^2)^{44}$.  This is used for instance by R.Stanley and D.Knuth and several other authors.  Be aware however that this is not universal notation and it may need to be explained to someone who has not seen it before.

Comment: My point in introducing this notation to you is to emphasize the difference between $[x^{20}y^{48}](3x-y^2)^{44}$ and $(3x-y^2)^{44}$.  These are very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coefficient of $x^{28}y^{30}$ must be zero, we get two contradictory values of $k=16$ and $k=15$.